# Python - how do delete content in a complicated folder without changing its structure?

Tags: python, directory, directory-structure

I have a folder with sub-folders, each can contain more sub-folders and so on. I want to delete all the files in all of them, but keeping the directory structure the same. Is there a built-in command or I have to write some recursive function for this using os.listdir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly stolen from the Python Documentation on [Files and Directories](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#files-and-directories) with the removal of directories omitted:

```
# Delete everything reachable from the directory named in "top",
# assuming there are no symbolic links.
# CAUTION:  This is dangerous!  For example, if top == '/', it
# could delete all your disk files.
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Thanks. I just added a bit to my question: I want to make sure system/hidden files are preserved. What changes do I have to make to your code? Thanks-

Comment: Then you would have to perform a check on `os.path.join(root, name)` to ensure it doesn't meet your preservation criteria, perhaps using  [`stat`](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) or perhaps using `string` comparison. This is entirely up to you to code!

Comment: Okay how to check if a file is a system/hidden file?

Answer (score 1):

See [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os
top = '/some/dir'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    for name in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

#check if file is hidden 
def is_hidden(filepath):
    name = os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(filepath))
    return name.startswith('.')

top = '/dir'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
    for name in files:
       #do not delete hidden files (as asked by OP in comments)
       if is_hidden(name) == false:  
          os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Comment: Preferably, you should provide some explanation or links or *something* besides just a wall of code.